Understand Laue condition intuitively
I understand that it is the necessary condition in elastic scattering for scattering to happen, and for the wave to stay coherent, thus it stays able to interfere with other diffracted rays. But I have trouble understanding why, physically and not geometrically, it is of this form :
$$\vec{k'}-\vec{k}=\vec{G_n}$$
My biggest problem is how to interpret the $\vec{G_n}$ in this equation, physically what does the "spacing" between lattice sites have to do with the wave vectors.

The translational symmetry of the lattice leads to momentum restrictions on allowed wave functions of the lattice. Think back to the simpler one dimension case of a diffraction grating.

@JonCuster I understand that there is a restrictions on G values but I don't understand how it translates to the incoming wave, also for basic grating, there is usually holes for the light to pass and solid to stop it, this leads to only some incident wave front to pass through, while here between atoms there is pretty much nothing so how come it still is discrete ?

A diffraction grating has no holes. The incoming wave sees a periodic potential, and the solution to the scattered wave(s) has to fit with that periodicity. This limits the allowed scattering conditions.

@JonCuster Ok, got it. But this leaves me with a question, how are $\vec{k}$,$\vec{k'}$ and $\vec{G}$ related. How is the momentum of the incoming wave related to the reciprocal lattice vector ?

The allowable scattered $k’$ are the incoming $k$ plus/minus a lattice momentum. Like diffraction,  the scattered energy is the same as the incident energy.
